# How to pack members of a struct for efficient cross platform code?

Tags: c++

Suppose I have two (unsigned short) 16-bit values that I need store in a struct. Should I store them together in a single 32-bit integer or as two unsigned short variables?

```
struct Foo {
unsigned CombinedValue;  // A

unsigned short Index;   //B
unsigned short Counter; //B
};
```

Which would be better **overall** for cross platform (x86, ARM, 32/64-bit) code in terms of code gen? Would the answer be the same if I was storing two 32-bit ints?

Comment: Given that the generic advice is to try and reorder your members for efficient packing especially if they're different sizes, but what's the general advice for same size members.

Comment: How do you know that `unsigned` is 32 bit?

Comment: Use the type that is appropriate for the data you need to hold. I default to `int` and it works pretty well.  These kinds of micro optimizations should really be avoided until you get the code working and you profile to determine that it is an issue.

Answer (score -1):

Store them in the way that makes the most semantic sense and let the optimizing compiler do what it's good at. If you need fixed-width 16-bit types you should also consider using the `<cstdint>` types like `uint16_t`; `unsigned short` is not guaranteed to always be 16 bits.

Related:
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/80084/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil

Comment: This was downvoted with no comment literally less than 5 seconds after it was posted, so I can only assume someone must have misclicked!